# pyspotify compilation ld error

Tags: compiling, libraries, ld, arm64

I'm trying to install mopidy-spotify on my freebox delta that allow me to install vm and is arm64 based
After many problems, i've manage to get most of the dependencies working and to get rid of most of the errors.
But am still struggling on libspotify when trying to compile pyspotify.
I've compiled successfully (i think) libspotify on my system using the sources from [that link](https://forum.kodi.tv/showthread.php?tid=125147&page=66)
but I'm always getting

here are the log output:

```
Obtaining file:///home/jc/pyspotify
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from pyspotify==2.1.3) (45.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from pyspotify==2.1.3) (1.14.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from cffi>=1.0.0->pyspotify==2.1.3) (2.20)
Installing collected packages: pyspotify
  Running setup.py develop for pyspotify
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/home/jc/pyspotify/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/home/jc/pyspotify/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' develop --no-deps
         cwd: /home/jc/pyspotify/
    Complete output (22 lines):
    running develop
    running egg_info
    writing pyspotify.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to pyspotify.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing requirements to pyspotify.egg-info/requires.txt
    writing top-level names to pyspotify.egg-info/top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'pyspotify.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'examples/tmp'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '__pycache__/*' found anywhere in distribution
    writing manifest file 'pyspotify.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    running build_ext
    generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/spotify._spotify.c'
    already up-to-date
    building 'spotify._spotify' extension
    aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/spotify._spotify.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/spotify._spotify.o
    aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/spotify._spotify.o -lspotify -o build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/spotify/_spotify.abi3.so
    /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/lib/libspotify.so when searching for -lspotify
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lspotify
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    error: command 'aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

please be free to ask for more informations
Any clues on that?

Comment: indeed you are right file return `ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, stripped`
I'm building it within the same system so I assumed (should not have) that it was building for 64 bit. so the question is more how can I tell it to build for 64 bit (I use make install prefix=/usr/local/) as I don't see the -m32 inside the makefile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're most likely trying to mix 32 bit and 64 bit libraries. 32 bit applications must be linked against 32 bit libraries whereas 64 bit applications must be linked against 64 bit libraries.

You can run `file /usr/local/lib/libspotify.so` to check if your library has been compiled for 32 bit or 64 bit.

You can instruct a GCC running on a 64 bit system to compile 32 bit code by setting the following environment variables:

```
CFLAGS=-m32 CXXFLAGS=-m32 make
```

Also see [/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible foo.so when searching for foo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16927885/usr-bin-ld-skipping-incompatible-foo-so-when-searching-for-foo).

Comment: unfortunately you're right, but after retrying, it turns out i was not compilling, but just installing. i didn't found any way to make it compile and I rather stop here, taking me too long. thanks for your time